# Prolog: Cast term into string?

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a Prolog program, which generates terms of this form:

```
:-op(803, xfy, →).

connect(X, Y, Result):-
    Result = (X → Y).
```

if I now call connect(a,b,R) my result is `R =  (a→b).` Is their a possibility to convert terms like (a→b) into a string within Prolog?

Background: I want to work with the results in Python. But if I transfer it with swiplserver or pyswip I get termini of this kind: `→(a, b)`. My hope is to solve that problem with such a typecast.

Comment: Did you read the tag usage guidance? The [term] tag is being burninated.

Comment: [Terms](https://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/groups/ssp/bookpages/quickprolog/node5.html) in prolog language have a unique and general approved datatype definition based on mathematical logic. It is not possible to rename it without reduce the key of understanding. It would be the same as u say the word class or string is being burniated in java or c++.

Comment: The burnination is already in progress, so it's really too late to object to its removal at this point. If you have an objection to a particular burnination request, though, the Meta posts are always featured for a few days beforehand to solicit feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use predicate [term_string/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_string/2) as follows:

```
?- connect(a, b, T), term_string(T, S).
T =  (a→b),
S = "a→b".
```

Alternatively, you can also use [term_to_atom/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_to_atom/2) or [format/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/3):

```
?- connect(a, b, T), term_to_atom(T, A).
T =  (a→b),
A = 'a→b'.

?- connect(a, b, T), format(string(S), '~w', T).
T =  (a→b),
S = "a→b".

?- connect(a, b, T), format(atom(A), '~w', T).
T =  (a→b),
A = 'a→b'.
```